# Add a listener to a TextView in TableRow

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, tablerow

I'm adding TableRow elements in the flow programatically.

```
TextView eq = new TextView(fa);
eq.setId(40);
eq.setText(Student.getEq());
eq.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
eq.setTextSize(12);
eq.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
tr_head.addView(eq);
```

I would like to know if we can add a listener to `eq` `TextView`s in my case. Is that possible?
Thank you for helping.

Comment: listener means `ClickListener` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: Yes, example, i just want to show a Toast when taping on `eq` TextView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try as to set `OnClickListener` for TextView :

```
TextView eq = new TextView(fa);
eq.setId(40);
eq.setText(Student.getEq());
eq.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
eq.setTextSize(12);
eq.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
eq.setClickable(true);  //<< make textview Clickable

eq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         //do you work here
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, yes. I did not figure out this. Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```
eq.setClickable(true);
eq.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do whatever stuff you wanna do here
    }
});
```

Comment: we need to make textview clickable

Answer (score 0):

```
TableRow tr=new TableRow(this);
TextView tv = new TextView("title");
tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
//add textview into tablerow
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         //do
    }
});
```